# Flurry Error Reporting for Android

Tags: android

Is there anyone using Flurry to generate reports for uncaught exceptions that could post some sample code on how to do this?

I don't see any example via Flurry themselves, and though I've seen code samples of custom exception reporters, I haven't seen a simple example of how to implement the basic error reporting just using Flurry.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

This is all good feedback. We're looking into adding full stack traces for error reporting which we'll hopefully see in our next major SDK release. We'll also look at filtering by device model.

In the meantime we've added a new REST API for exporting your error reports if you want to do your own analysis. If you need help using it you can just contact our support or message me.

Sean / CTO / Flurry, Inc.

Answer (score 4):

Flurry does it automatically (if you have it running). However, the error reporting is lame. They only catch the message w/o giving you the stack trace, so you may end up seeing (for example) that people are getting lots of `NullPointerException`s, but you won't have any idea where, or how, they're happening. If you try to do it yourself with the `FlurryAgent.onEvent()` method you'll quickly discover that they limit you to 255 characters.

If you need detailed error reporting it really is better to roll your own right now.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yeah, it looks like the Flurry error reporting is basically not worth implementing, which is weird because if they just allowed you to capture the full stack trace it would be pretty nice. The error module in their web interface has a key M = Method, which made me think you could at least capture the method that threw the error, but I don't see how you'd even do that.

So as you suggest, I'll probably end up rolling my own, probably implementing one similar to others I've seen that prompt the user to email the stack trace back to me.

Answer (score 1):

I wasn't going to post this initially, but since it sounds like Flurry's error reporting sucks, you should check [android-remote-stacktrace](http://code.google.com/p/android-remote-stacktrace/).  It sends the stack trace to a url, which you can use to redirect it to an e-mail or just gather it on the server.

Comment: Hey Geek Could U pls guide me start learning the basics of flurry analytics in android? Where can i find its tutorial kind of things?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not using it for  uncaught exceptions , but you can catch it and then send it to flurry.

Answer (score 0):

I am using bugsense for error reports. It catches full stack trace when an uncaught exception happens and also gives some useful information about the device - OS version, you app's version, is WiFi available on the device, etc. You can add custom messages and tags for specific events.

I've already fixed a couple crashes in my app thanks to it.

Answer (score 0):

Since people are posting alternatives for getting stack traces, I'll recommend ACRA. [ACRA](http://code.google.com/p/acra/) can send the stack trace to a spreadsheet on google drive/docs. Or you can also have it send to your server if you wish too. By default it also includes phone model, android version, memory of device, and other data too.